# android AlarmClock set volume and ringtone

Tags: android, android-alarms

i need to add an alarm with a preset ringtone and at max volume
but i don't understand how i can pass this info to AlarmClock....
i have the ringtone in my res/raw (inside apk) and i use this code:

```
Intent i = new Intent(AlarmClock.ACTION_SET_ALARM);
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);    
i.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_HOUR, oratimer);
i.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_MINUTES, minutitimer);
i.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_RINGTONE, saveSong(context, R.raw.song).toString());
i.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_SKIP_UI, true);
context.startActivity(i);
```

this is the saveSong function:

```
public Uri saveSong(Context context, int song) {
    byte[] buffer = null;
    InputStream fIn = context.getResources().openRawResource(song);
    int size = 0;

    try {
        size = fIn.available();
        buffer = new byte[size];
        fIn.read(buffer);
        fIn.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        return null;
    }

    String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/Ringtones/";
    String filename = "song" + ".mp3";

    boolean exists = (new File(path)).exists();
    if (!exists) {
        new File(path).mkdirs();
    }
    exists = (new File(path+filename)).exists();
    if (!exists) {
        FileOutputStream save;
        try {
            save = new FileOutputStream(path + filename);
            save.write(buffer);
            save.flush();
            save.close();
            context.sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED, Uri.fromFile(new File(path + filename))));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            return null;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            return null;
        }
    }
    return Uri.fromFile(new File(path+filename));
}
```

but the alarm is made with the default ringtone at the default volume (like 70%?)
any hint for solve this?
tnx

Answer (score -2):

I Think this would work for you

```
     mp = new MediaPlayer();
     mp.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM);
```

Comment: sorry i don't understand how this can be usefull ....
i'm not using the mediaplayer but the alarmclock...